# All checkboxes are checking out

Tags: php, mysql, sql, checkbox, mysqli

I've got a question.

I've got a page with checkboxes generated with the database. When we press the checkbox and submit it, it is working fine and it is updating in the database. But when I try to uncheck "1" checkbox it is checking out all checkboxes which are selected.

Query:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                foreach ($_POST['untrain'] as $room_id => $user_id) {
                    // This query needs protection from SQL Injection!
                    $user_id;
                $untrainQuery = "UPDATE room_users SET trained = '1'  WHERE user_id = $user_id AND room_id = $room_id";
                $db->update($untrainQuery);

                }

                }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                foreach ($_POST['amk'] as $room_id => $user_id) {
                    // This query needs protection from SQL Injection!
                    $user_id;
                $untrainedQuery = "UPDATE room_users SET trained = '0'  WHERE user_id = $user_id AND room_id = $room_id";
                $db->update($untrainedQuery);

                }

                }
```

Checkboxes:

```
<?php if($room->trained == 1) { ?> <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $room->user_id; ?>" name="amk[<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>]"> <input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $room->user_id; ?>" name="trained[<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>]" checked> <?php echo "Y"; } else{ ?> <input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $room->user_id; ?>" name="untrain[<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>]"> <?php echo "N"; }?> </td>
                <Td><?php if($room->active == 1) { ?> <input type='checkbox' name="<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>" checked> <?php echo "Active"; } else { ?> <input type='checkbox' name="<?php echo $room->room_id; ?>"  <?php echo "Inactive"; } ?>
```

I used the "trick" with the input type hidden, but it is checking out all checked checkboxes..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have already posted this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29486911/checkboxes-are-checking-out-randomly?rq=1

Comment: That's not the same question sir,.

Comment: Why do you have 2 checkboxes for the same property of a room? Why don't you use 1 checkbox per room for the property trained. Then in the PHP you only have to check whether or not it has been checked.

Comment: @blablabla Could you explain me how? I'm a pretty newb in this

Comment: You have a checkbox to set a room as trained and one to set a room as untrained. When the form gets submitted, both will be in the results, so both queries will run. This makes that when the checkboxes with the name 'amk[]' are set, the first checkbox doesn't matter anymore.